# Treant Collapsable node text orientation

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, svg

I've been playing with Treant tree diagrams and run into a little problem i cant seem to rectify. im looking to edit the collapsable example such that it will take text instead of pictures. if i change collopsable.jsfrom

```
image: "img/woodhouse.png"
```

To

```
text: "This is a test"
```

The result is vertical text within the node. I've had a play wihtin the `collapsable.css` file to see if i can reformat using;

```
writing-mode: vertical-lr;  white-space: nowrap; text-orientation: upright;
```

But all letters are equally spaced making it difficult to read.

I'd love to be pointed in the right direction.

Apologies for not including all of the code but hopefully someone is sufficiently verse with treant to help or someone a little more experienced happy to replicate.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

did you figure this out.  It should be

text: {name: "This is a test"}

Answer (score -1):

```
var simple_chart_config = {
    chart: {
        container: "#OrganiseChart-simple"
    },
    
    nodeStructure: {
        text: { name: "Parent node" },
        children: [
            {
                text: { name: "First child" }
            },
            {
                [enter image description here][1]text: { name: "Second child" }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Demo Link: https://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/examples/super-simple

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).